# Adding MailChimp Shortcode in Theme with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mailchimp

I have the following website: https://www.ajagrawal.com

Currently in my website, I am trying to edit the hero section and replace the name, email and button fields with a custom wordpress form that was made with the plugin. Right now the emails are stored in Wordpress, but I want them in Mailchimp.

I know which code in my theme that form pertains to which is the following:

```
if(function_exists('newsletter_form')):
          $output .=  '<div class="row">';
          $output .=  '<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">';
          $output .=  '<form method="post" action="'.home_url('/').'?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">';
          $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
          $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="text" name="nn" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($name_placehodler).'">';
          $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-user"></span></div>';
          $output .=  '</div>';
          $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
          $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="email" name="ne" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($email_placeholder).'">';
          $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></div>';
          $output .=  '</div>';
          $output .=  '<input class="newsletter-submit c-btn type-1 size-4 full" type="submit" value="'.esc_html($btn_text).'">';
          $output .=  '</form>';
          $output .=  '</div>';
          $output .=  '</div>';
        endif;
```

Here is my mailchimp shortcode that represents the form.

```
[mc4wp_form id="2198"]
```

I've tried editing the code and inserting it multiple ways and even ended up crashing the site and still no luck. Considering my goal, is this the right approach (putting the shortcode in the PHP code)?

If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `do_shortcode` function.

Examples in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/#user-contributed-notes):

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode( '' );


// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
echo do_shortcode( '[iscorrect]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/iscorrect]' );


// Enable the use of shortcodes in text widgets.
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

// Use shortcodes in form like Landing Page Template.
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' );

// Store the short code in a variable.
$var = do_shortcode( '' );
echo $var;
```

So in your case something like:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2198"]' );
```

should do the trick.

EDIT:
Something like this should work:

```
          $output .=  '<div class="row">';
          $output .=  '<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">';
          $output .=  do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2198"]' );
          $output .=  '</div>';
          $output .=  '</div>';
```

Then do whatever you want with output - probably will have to echo it...

Comment: Would I delete that whole if statement and include echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2198"]' ); or would I remove certain lines of it?

Comment: From what I can understand from your code I think you need to change the if statement to check if the form with the id 2198 exists and if it does then add the layout - the row, col-* divs and then the shortcode echo ( basically the form in your code gets replaced by the echo shortcode and the if statement changes ) if unclear let me know

Comment: Gotcha I'm currently familiarizing myself with PHP. The logic makes sense, but how exactly to "add the layout - the row, col-* divs" and then echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2198"]' ); I'm confused.

Comment: Hi Jantea, any clarification?

Comment: @RohitTigga: sorry, missed your comment yesterday, I've updated my answer with the code that you should be able to use